# return multiple rows from an asmx service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, datatable, asmx

I have a web service method which i'd like to return multiple rows from a datatable.

I am familiar with returning values from web service methods but not multiple rows from a datatable. What is the best way to go about doing this? Do I need to return an array or `list<>`?

My code method is setup like this.

```
[WebMethod]
public void UpdateBold(int count, float lat, float lng)
{
DataTable dt = new Gallery().DisplayNearestByLatLong(count, lat, lng);

// return code here
}
```

Comment: I'd updated the answer for your ajax call. you should make your service json serialize.

Comment: Don't appreciate that you accepted Saaed's answer when mine were more detailed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create new type for your data table item and return array of this data

```
    public class sample
    {
        public string val1;
        public string val2;

    }
[WebMethod]
public sample[] UpdateBold(int count, float lat, float lng)

{

            DataTable dt = new Gallery().DisplayNearestByLatLong(count, lat, lng);
            var samples = new List<sample>();

            foreach(DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                var s = new sample();
                s.val1 = item[0].ToString();
                s.val2 = item[1].ToString();
                samples.Add(s);
            }
            return samples.ToArray();
}
```

for Ajax:

for consuming see http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/
but you should make your webservice to serialize JSON, for this see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183.aspx

Comment: That looks promising. I am trying to consume this using JSON in jquery but it's not working. Do you know how I would work that? Or another way to test it?

$.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../../../WebServices/Gallery.asmx/Test",
                //data: "{count: '" + count + "', lat: '" + lat + "', lng: '" + long + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    alert(msg.d); //test(msg);
                }
            });

Comment: @codemonkey, If you didn't resolve your JSON problem, you can simply test this service with win app.

Answer (score 6):

I would return an Array of light-weight DTOs.

Ex, DTO:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And in your web serivce:

```
[WebMethod]
public Example[] GetExamples()
{
      return new Example[]{
          new Example { Name = "Test", Value = 100 },
          new Example { Name = "Test 2", Value = 500 }
      };      
}
```

Comment: No no no, I'm know about DTO, but I left this comment because of your comment for OP, `why OP doesn't mark your answer as answer`, IMHO your answer is not more detail than what I said. I removed prev comment :)